# How do I create a link to an entry using entry's id?

Tags: entry-type

This is a beginner question:

**How do I create a link to an entry using entry's id?**

I tried several combinations, such as `{{ entry.getUrl(my_id) }}`, `{{ entry.url.id(my_id) }}`, etc. but failed to found the correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your example fail is that you are using the `entry` variable. You are trying to call the function `getUrl` on the model `entry`, but the function (or model) doesn't exist yet, and has to be created (fetched).

**Example:**

You can use [craft.entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) to fetch the [EntryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel), and than output its url:

```twig
{% set my_id = 5 %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(my_id).first() %}
{{ entry.url }}
```

If you are in an entry loop, it works the same way:

```twig
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog') %}
    {{ entry.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add this link but all I got is a PHP error: CException — Craft\ElementCriteriaModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "url". Same problem after chaining the 'entry' and 'my_id'. Any idea?

Comment: @Romainpoirier Just added `.first()` to the 2nd line of the first code block. That should fix your error.

Answer (score 2):

As a shorthand, you could also use [Reference Tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/reference-tags) along with the `parseRefs` filter, like this:

```
<a href="{{ '{entry:123:url}' | parseRefs }}">{{ '{entry:123:title}' | parseRefs }}</a>
```

(Performance-wise, I'm not actually sure how this compares to spinning up the ElementCriteriaModel. It wouldn't surprise me if Craft caches entry data it queries, so it's not running a separate query for each reference tag... but I'm not sure about that.)

Comment: Question about whether this is performant, posted here: [http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/linking-to-specific-entries-in-twig-how-performant-is-reference-tags-parsing](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/linking-to-specific-entries-in-twig-how-performant-is-reference-tags-parsing)