# What's the best way to link to an entry in a template?

Tags: templating, url, entry

I have the following code and I'm looking for the best way to link to another entry page.

```
<a href="#" class="btn-quote">request a quote</a>
```

I tried something like this with no luck:

```
<a href="{{ entry.getLink('Get a Quote') }}" class="btn-quote">request a quote</a>
```

Here's the entry: http://grab.by/Ax6s

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll want to retrieve that entry specifically...

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug('get-a-quote').first %}
```

Once you've got the entry that you want to target, you can easily link to it like this:

```
<a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="btn-quote">request a quote</a>
```

Comment: For some reason when I use the code above, it's not outputting the entry field below.  I created another discussion regarding the issue. Here's a [link](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/entry-field-not-outputting-after-set-code-in-template?noredirect=1#comment3951_2685).  Maybe you can help me figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Just left an answer on that thread... Looks like you'll need a different variable name than "entry" (since "entry" is already taken).

Answer (score 2):

As a shorthand, you could also use [Reference Tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/reference-tags) along with the `parseRefs` filter, like this:

```
<a href="{{ '{entry:123:url}' | parseRefs }}">Request a Quote</a>
```

*(Similar question/answer posted [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-an-entry-using-entrys-id).)*

Comment: Question about whether this is performant, posted here: [http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/linking-to-specific-entries-in-twig-how-performant-is-reference-tags-parsing](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/linking-to-specific-entries-in-twig-how-performant-is-reference-tags-parsing)