# Entry field not outputting after {% set... %} code in template

Tags: templating, field, entry, set

I have an `{entry.footer}` field outputting just fine everywhere before `{% set entry... %}`
Added `{% endset %}` tags after closing anchor tag and caused an error. Any idea what the issue is?

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block home_slider %}
{% include 'global/home-slider.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
            <main id="main" role="main">
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="holder-top">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <div class="wrap">
                                     {{ entry.body }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="three-columns">
                                <div class="wrap">
                                    {% for block in entry.threeHomepageImages.type('images') %}
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="image-block">
                                                <div class="image">
                                                    {% if block.image|length %}
                                                        <a href="{{ block.pageLink.first().getUrl() }}"><img src="images/{{ block.image.first }}.jpg" alt="{{ block.alt }}"></a>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h1><a href="{{ block.pageLink.first().getUrl() }}">{{ block.imageTitle }}</a></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-holder">
                                <div class="btn-wrap">
                                    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug('get-a-quote').first %}
                                    <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="btn-quote">request a quote</a>
                                    {% endset %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="holder-bottom">
                        <div class="quote">
                            {{ entry.footer }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Not seeing the `{% endset %}`. What error are you getting where?

Comment: when I include `{% endset %}` I get the following error: 
**Internal Server Error

Unexpected tag name "endset" (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined near line 8)** I added entire template code to original post.

Comment: Definitely ditch the `{% endset %}`, per [Marion's suggestion below](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2689/45). Do you have [Dev Mode](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode) enabled on your local site? What happens when you put `{{ dump(entry) }}` after your `{% set entry %}` tag?

Comment: It outputs a ton of code...same either way.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your problem... You're redefining `entry` halfway down the page.

This page clearly uses the section's built-in routing functionality. I can tell because you use `entry.body` near the top of your page *without explicitly declaring the value of `entry`*.

However, you later on use `{% set entry %}` to **reassign** the value of `entry`. Based on the new value of `entry`, the `entry.footer` property no longer exists or is empty.

**How to fix it...**

Instead of `{% set entry %}`, use a *different* variable name:

```
{% set getQuoteEntry = craft.entries.slug('get-a-quote').first %}
<a href="{{ getQuoteEntry.url }}" class="btn-quote">request a quote</a>
```

This will leave the original value of `entry` untouched, and you'll still have access to `entry.footer` at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Where do I declare the value of {{ getQuoteEntry.url }}. Would that be done as a global variable?

Comment: Just updated my answer to clarify... `entry` is an Entry, created automatically for you by Craft's magical routing system. `getQuoteEntry` is **also** an Entry, but you'll need to set it manually.

Comment: `entry` is **this** entry. `getQuoteEntry` is **a separate** entry.

Answer (score 3):

The [twig set tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) has two syntaxes. You can use it like this:

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
```

or like this:

```
{% set foo %}bar{% endset %}
```

They are both useful in different ways.

The error you were getting was about mixing them.

Comment: still doesn't solve issue however, as nothing in the `{{ entry.footer }}` field will output when added below that `{% set... %}` code.  Neither of the syntaxes are working for me, unless I'm still missing something.